# docker, get container name, not container id in nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker

I saw an answer already on this [url](https://gist.github.com/pulkitsinghal/c1b40aa9acb2881505f26eb6992fb794) but it's actually returning the container id instead of container name.

Code from URL

```
const os = require('os');
console.log( os.hostname() );
```

In docker, container id is a long string that looks like `4e600c35e164...`

while container name is a meaningful name given to this machine for instance `customer` and that's what I'm trying to get in nodejs.

**docker-compose**

```
customerservice:
    image: node:10
    container_name: customer
    command: bash -c "npm install && npm install nodemon -g && nodemon --exec npm start"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Comment: You could pass `hostname: customer` also in your compose, whats it showing on cmd line when you attach?

Comment: `process.env.HOSTNAME` is returning the same long string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot do it without binding your hosts's `docker.sock` file into the container, which allows you to run docker commands or contact docker's API from inside the container. See [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-run-docker-command-inside-a-docker-container/337) for instance. Notice that it requires you to install docker in the container, and that it comes with security risks. Not such a great option.

---

An alternative would be to simply add an environment variable (and manually set it to whatever you want) to your container using the [`environment`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) key in `docker-compose.yaml`.

---

And finally, if you're alright with modifying your compose file, you could use a recent feature: templated docker configs. The idea is, a config is a file that is accessible in the container. It can be templated, for instance it could look like

```
{{ .Name }}
```

which would be replaced by the name of your container (try running `docker container inspect <container_name>` to see this `Name`. You could create this config once using

```
docker config create --template-driver golang <config_name> <path/to/file>
```

and then use it in every single container by adding a `configs:` section at the root of your compose file that points to your external config, and link it to your containers (notice the compose file version, I think you need `3.7` at least):

```
# docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.7'

configs:
  <config_alias_inside_this_file>:
    external: true
    name: <config_name>

services:
  <service_name>:
    configs:
      - source: <config_alias_inside_this_file>
        target: <path/inside/container>
        # uid: '1000'  # You can set file mode, owner uid and group gid
        # gid: '1000'  # here if you need to, check the "long syntax" subsection
        # mode: 0644   # at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#configs
    ...
```

Unfortunately you cannot create templated configs from within a compose file (yet), but that isn't really an issue.

Comment: Hi, do you have any idea what `--template-driver` is used for?

Comment: @DoryNguyen Yes, I don't know the list of supported drivers, but using `golang` means that the syntax used to parse and replace variables in your config will be the golang template driver: everything between `{{ ... }}` will be interpreted (see https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/ for examples).

I'm not sure if there are other drivers available for docker config, but other examples would be twig (also using `{{ ... }}` but with a different syntax inside), old-school php (`<?php ... ?>`), etc. Golang does the job well, so maybe no one took the time to implement other options.